# Show Hibernate Search statistics on Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-search, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot application v. 2.3.0 with following dependencies:

- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
- hibernate-search-orm version 5.11.5
- spring-boot-starter-actuator

My `application.properties` looks like this

```
# Enabling Actuator for all
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

# Show Hibernate statistics. This works!
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true

# Show Hibernate Search statistics. This works not!
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider = filesystem
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase = /path/to/index
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.generate_statistics=true
```

I can see the statistics of hibernate under `/actuator/metrics`, but the statistics for hibernate search do not appear. Do you know, how I can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just guessing, but... There's probably some component in Spring that translates statistics provided by Hibernate ORM into something that appears on your webapp. As far as I know, Spring doesn't provide any integration of Hibernate Search, so this "translation" component is missing for Hibernate Search, thus you don't see anything.

I'd suggest you have a look at how exactly the Hibernate ORM statistics appear on your console; you'll probably need to implement something similar for Hibernate Search.

Comment: Thank you, feels like the correct way. I'll implement it by my own.